# null pointer exception in sherlock action bar with option menu

Tags: actionbarsherlock, searchview

I want sherlock action bar with default sherlock search widget.The search icon is displayed on sherlock action bar but onclick its force closing .My Logcat shown below

04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.toString(MenuItemImpl.java:490)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:201)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:950)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:490)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:108)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-17 11:44:48.877: E/AndroidRuntime(530):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

The menu.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
  android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
  android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
  android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
   />
  </menu>
```

The code in sherlock activity

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.tvguide_menu, menu);
     }
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
      Log.e("", "itemselected" +item.getItemId());
       switch(item.getItemId()) 
        {
            case R.id.menu_search:
                Toast.makeText(TVBuddyMainActivity.this,"search selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(TVBuddyMainActivity.this,CustomSearch.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
     return true;
}
```

pls help me with this logcat....

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in version 4.3.0 of ActionBarSherlock, I fixed it in this way:

```
--- a/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragmentActivity.java
+++ b/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragmentActivity.java
@@ -198,7 +198,7 @@ public class SherlockFragmentActivity extends Watson implements OnActionModeStar

     @Override
     public final boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, android.view.MenuItem item) {
-        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "[onMenuItemSelected] featureId: " + featureId + ", item: " + item);
+       // if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "[onMenuItemSelected] featureId: " + featureId + ", item: " + item);

         if (featureId == Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL && !mIgnoreNativeSelected) {
             mIgnoreNativeSelected = true;
```